# Concerning the inequality from Kolmogorov's continuity theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, integral-inequality

Let $\mathbb{I}\subset[0,\infty)$ be a compact interval. We call a stochastic process $Y=(Y_t)_{t\in\mathbb{I}}$ *Kolmogorov-continuous* if

$$\exists\,\alpha, \beta, C>0 \quad \text{ such that } \quad \mathbb{E}|Y_t - Y_s|^\alpha \leq C|t-s|^{1+\beta}\quad \text{for each } s,t\in\mathbb{I}.$$

Given an an $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued process $Y=(Y^1_t, \cdots, Y^d_t)_{t\in\mathbb{I}}$ whose coordinate processes $(Y^i_t)_{t\in\mathbb{I}}$ are mutually independent and each Kolmogorov-continuous, does it hold that that $Y$ is also Kolmogorov-continuous?

(I thought that this is true and shouldn't be too difficult to prove, but the obvious attempts using Jensen's and Hölder's inequality didn't work out..) It'd be happy to see a counterexample if the above assertion is in fact wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One crude approach is to note that, writing $\|\cdot\|$ for the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^d$, we have $\|X\| \le d^{1/2} \max_i |X^i|$, and therefore
$$\|Y_t - Y_s\|^\alpha \le d^{\alpha/2} \max_i |Y_t^i - Y_s^i|^\alpha \le d^{\alpha/2} \sum_i |Y_t^i - Y_s^i|^\alpha$$
and thus
$$\mathbb{E} \|Y_t-Y_s\|^\alpha \le d^{\alpha/2} \sum_i \mathbb{E}|Y_t^i - Y_s^i|^\alpha \le C d^{\alpha/2} \sum_i |t-s|^{1+\beta} \le C d^{1+\alpha/2} |t-s|^{1+\beta}$$
so that $Y$ is Kolmogorov-continuous with parameters $\alpha, \beta, Cd^{1+\alpha/2}$ (the latter is probably not the best constant).

The independence is not needed.

Comment: Many thanks, @NateEldredge ! However, the coordinate processes are not assumed to be 'uniformly Kolmogorov-continuous', i.e. each $Y^i$ will be Kolmogorov-continuous w.r.t. constants $\kappa_i:=(\alpha_i, \beta_i, C_i)$ but in general $\kappa_i\neq\kappa_j$ for $i\neq j$.

Comment: By an obvious estimation of the RHS of each continuity-inequality (using that $\mathbb{I}$ is compact) one may of course assume that $(\beta_i, C_i)=(\beta_j, C_j)$ for each $i,j\in\{1, \ldots, d\}$ without loss of generality. I do not see, however, how one may assume wlog that $\alpha_i=\alpha_j$..

Comment: @fsp-b: I see; I don't know how to fix that either.  Though note that for many purposes, it would suffice to pass to a bounded metric and consider $(1 \wedge |Y_t-Y_s|)^\alpha$, in which case you can then just take the smallest of the $\alpha_i$.

Comment: Thank you once more. I will consider the capped case you suggested.